# Error in opening a application through command prompt when the application is deployed to remote site

Tags: python, angular, remote-server, user-interaction

This is the error I am getting when I try to execute a line in the command prompt like the process involved in opening a popup window:

> [Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.]

How to make the application run in the admin client of the remote site to UserInteractive mode the application is built using Python and angular.